# PWM driven MOSFET to power a coil

Tags: pwm, h-bridge, mosfet-driver, coil, electromagnet

I need to power a coil (electromagnet to be precise) using a PWM singal generated by an arduino or a 555 timer.

I can esily power the coil when the PWM signal is in the HIGH (5v) state using a simple N-CHANNEL MOSFET.

My problem is that I can't find a way to power the coil when the PWM signal is in the LOW state (-5v) in order to reverse the polarity of the magnetic field cerated by the EM.

After some research I assume that I need to use an H bridge [Like described here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/320946/pwm-control-coil) however my electromagnet will probably draw a lot of power, using a driver like [DRV8837](https://www.ti.com/product/DRV8837) won't be sufficient.

Any help would be much appreciated on how to design a proper H bridge circuit.

Comment: First step is to determine what voltage is needed to power the coil and how much current it will draw.

Comment: First requirement is actually knowing how much power (current/voltage) the H-bridge has to handle. One can't design anything to "probably" and "a lot".

Comment: Define EM parameters L, DCR, Power rated, or needed, then compute (X(f) + DCR) * I^2 = VAR+ Pd , the Flyback diode reverses the EMF.or the bridge Must also be factored for diode or Ron loss.

Comment: f and Ron/DCR are critical factors to compute conversion efficiency as well as parasitics for oscillation and resulting Q

Comment: wait ... how do you get an arduino to output -5V?

Comment: You also need to think about design of the electromagnet if you're making your own.  Especially if you're inverting the field, your needed field strength and peak to peak oscillation frequency are design factors.  Your core material and magnetic field guide shape too.  With large, high frequency, or high current inductors oscillating you may need to think about EMI radiation.